# Cannot filter a strucure of Strings with spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to filter lines from a dataframe with this structure :

```
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- qty: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: timestamp (containsNull = true)
```

For example in this dataframe I only want the first row :

```
+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    age  | qty        |dates                                                             |
+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  54     |           1|  [2020-12-31 12:15:20, 2021-12-31 12:15:20]                      |
|  45     |           1|  [2020-12-31 12:15:20, 2018-12-31 12:15:20, 2019-12-31 12:15:20] |
+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Here is my code :

```
 val result = sqlContext
     .table("scores")
 
 
 result.filter(array_contains(col("dates").cast("string"),
 2021)).show(false)
```

But I'm getting this error :

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'array_contains(
> due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be an array followed by a value of same type as the > array members;

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `rlike` to check if each array element contains 2021. `array_contains` check for exact match, not partial match.

```
result.filter("array_max(transform(dates, x -> string(x) rlike '2021'))").show(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the ArrayType and then make your proceessing as You want: cast the column as String then apply your filter:

```
 val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("SparkByExamples")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    import java.sql.Timestamp
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    def convertToTimeStamp(s: String) = {
      val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
      val parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(s)
      new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime)

    }


    val data = Seq(
      Row(54, 1, Array(convertToTimeStamp("2020-12-31 12:15:20"), convertToTimeStamp("2021-12-31 12:15:20"))),
      Row(45, 1, Array(convertToTimeStamp("2020-12-31 12:15:20"), convertToTimeStamp("2018-12-31 12:15:20"), convertToTimeStamp("2019-12-31 12:15:20")))
    )
    val Schema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("age", IntegerType, nullable = true),
      StructField("qty", IntegerType, nullable = true),
      StructField("dates", ArrayType(TimestampType, containsNull = true), nullable = true)

    ))

    val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
    var df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, Schema)
    df.show()
    df.printSchema()
    df = df.withColumn("exp",f.explode(f.col("dates")))
    df.filter(f.col("exp").cast(StringType).contains("2021")).show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#exists) function to check whether `dates` array contains a date with year 2021:

```scala
df.filter("exists(dates, x -> year(x) = 2021)").show(false)

//+---+---+------------------------------------------+
//|age|qty|dates                                     |
//+---+---+------------------------------------------+
//|54 |1  |[2020-12-31 12:15:20, 2021-12-31 12:15:20]|
//+---+---+------------------------------------------+
```

If you want to use `array_contains`, you need to transform the timestamp elements into year:

```scala
df.filter("array_contains(transform(dates, x -> year(x)), 2021)").show(false)
```